# Regex - From PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, regex, markdown

An user was kind enough to help me out with my regex in PHP, but now I'm realizing that I need it in JS too. I've been spending a crazy amount of time testing/experimenting, but without success.

In JS, I would like to turn this :

```
[data-user="12345-6789" data-userId="3456-789"]John Smith[/] ...Blablabla some other text... [data-user="4567-891011" data-userId="5678-9101112"]Foo Bar[/]
```

Into this :

```
<span data-user="12345-6789" data-userId="3456-789">John Smith</span> ...Blablabla some other text... <span data-user="4567-891011" data-userId="5678-9101112">Foo Bar</span>
```

Here is my PHP regex, which works perfectly :

```
$regex = '~\[(data-user="[\d-]+")\s+(data-userId="[\d-]+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[\/\]\s*(.*)~is';

while (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    $string = preg_replace($regex, "&lt;span $1 $2&gt;$3&lt;/span&gt;$4", trim(strip_tags($string)));
}
```

P.S. I'm fully aware that parsing HTML with a regex is frowned upon, but since everything is consistent, I thought this would be the best approach.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: What Javascript have you tried?

Comment: @Kyll Looks like it's just *"How to I make this code do the same thing in JavaScript"*.

Comment: Ah. Then, Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us [what you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks to me like translating it verbatim works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lruqjz4a/) Just have to mind the changes in the regex itself, namely, changing the `~` to `/` and removing the `s` modifier.

```
var regex = /\[(data-user="[\d-]+")\s+(data-userId="[\d-]+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[\/\]\s*(.*)/i;
var str = '[data-user="12345-6789" data-userId="3456-789"]John Smith[/] ...Blablabla some other text... [data-user="4567-891011" data-userId="5678-9101112"]Foo Bar[/]';
var html = str;

while (regex.test(html)) {
    html = html.replace(regex, '&lt;span $1 $2&gt;$3&lt;/span&gt;$4');
}
console.log(html);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This shows me how close I was. I did not remove the 's' modifier. Thanks again.

Comment: You cannot use the `/s`modifier in JavaScript. Replace all dots with `[\s\S]` instead.

Comment: @stribizhev Understood. Thank you.

Comment: Also, `preg_replace`performs a global search and replace (in JS, you need `/g`). However, I doubt you need that global search here.

Answer (score 2):

I simplified the RegEx and made it less hard-coded, allowing you to have other attributes and such inside the tag as well.

In JavaScript you can just use `String.prototype.replace()` as it accepts RegEx.

```js
var string = '[data-user="12345-6789" data-userId="3456-789"]John Smith[/] ...Blablabla some other text... [data-user="4567-891011" data-userId="5678-9101112"]Foo Bar[/]'

var regex = /\[([^\]]*)\]\s*([^\[]*)\s*\[\/\]/ig;

console.log(string.replace(regex, '<span $1>$2</span>'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I went with @Zsw's answer as it allowed me to keep things a little more strict, but I might take your approach if I ever need a little more loose. Thank you.